# Output the total amount spent by the customer and the item on which he/she spent the most

Tags: mysql, sql

There is a table like this, how can I get `customer_id`, `amount_spent`, `top_item` out of it?

`amount_spent` the amount spent on all items by this customer

`top_item`, which displays the name of the item for which the customer has spent the most money

[image: Table]

I have tried the following query, however I cannot output the top_1 item with it

```sql
select customer_id, sum(item_number * item_price) as amount_spent_1m 
from temp
group by customer_id
```

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/CMwc23b_).

Comment: what if there's a tie for top item?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it as below :

```
select customer_id,  sum(item_number * item_price) as amount_spent_1m, 
item_name as top_item_1m
from temp
group by customer_id, item_name
order by amount_spent_1m desc;
```

It gives me the following result :

[image]

Comment: Yes but, need to output one line for the customer, with the total amount spent and the item he/she spent the most on. But here the customer is output twice

Comment: OK,
I got your question now.
I will update the answer in a while

Comment: @Avidan You should be able to do it with window functions. Or turn this query into a CTE, then use one of the techniques at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group-mysql?rq=1 to get the top row for each customer.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure there is a way to do this with one less step but my brain is not seeing it right now -

```
SELECT customer_id, amount_spent, item_name AS top_item
FROM (
  SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY item_total DESC) rn,
    SUM(item_total) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id) amount_spent
  FROM (
    SELECT customer_id, item_id, item_name, SUM(item_price * item_number) item_total
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY customer_id, item_id, item_name
  ) t1
) t2
WHERE rn = 1
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/XC4rKV3H)